# How do you get the ASP.NET MVC action of the page (i.e. one from URL) rather than current action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

Given the following simplified ASP.NET MVC scenario:

1. A user navigates to a page http://www.mysite.com/Home/Index  ("Index" explictly included for clarity)
2. On that page is a `$.ajax({..}`) jQuery post that calls a method within Home controller, e.g. `/Home/GetProducts`
3. In the `GetProducts()` method I need to get the Index action name - bear in mind that at runtime I don't know whether the user is browsing `Home/Index`, `Home/About`, `Home/Contact`, etc., as `GetProducts` could be called from anywhere.

I can't for the life of me get the page action (e.g. Index, About, Contact, etc.) in the scope of the `GetProducts()` method.

I have tried the following:

```
// returns "GetProducts"
string actionName1 = RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
// returns "GetProducts"
string actionName2 = ControllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
// ParentActionViewContext == null
string actionName3 = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Comment: Note: I could pass in the action name from the calling view, but I want to avoid having to do that.

Comment: Sorry, there's no other way, you will have to go that way due to the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it. HTTP is a stateless protocol which doesn't keep any track of previous requests. So simply pass it as parameter to the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Home")',
    data: { currentAction: '@ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")' },
    success: function(result) {
        // do something with the results
    }
});
```

and your `GetProducts` controller action will take it as parameter:

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(string currentAction)
{
    ...
}
```